# Django if statement for context usage in template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**What i am trying to achieve:**
i am getting data from an API, i want to display that data in my template only if the conditions are met.

**What i tried #1:**
i added a boolean in my model that is linked to the API called "accessconfirmed" and then
in my views i added a if statement saying if access is confirmed then display this context and if not then display this other context. i dont get an error but my data from the API is no longer displaying, i get nothing. here is the code in the views.py

VIEWS:

```
def projectdetailscoins(request, pk):
    coin = Coin.objects.get(id=pk)
    notifications = Notification.objects.all()
    accessconfirmed = Coin.is_api_access
    api_coin_number_variable = coin.api_coin_number
    url = 'XXX'
    parameters = {
        'slug': coin.api_slug,
        'convert': 'USD',
    }
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'XXX'
    }
    session = Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
    api_price = response.json()
    if accessconfirmed == True:
        context = {'coin':coin, 'notifications':notifications,
        'gimmeprice':api_price['data'][api_coin_number_variable]['quote']['USD']['price'],
        'gimme24h':api_price['data'][api_coin_number_variable]['quote']['USD']['percent_change_24h'],
        'accessconfirmed':accessconfirmed,
    }
    else:
        context = {'coin':coin, 'notifications':notifications,}
    
    return render(request, 'blog/project_details_coin.html', context)
```

**What i tried #2:**
i also tried changing the if statement from

```
if accessconfirmed == True:
```

to

```
if accessconfirmed:
```

the data displays correctly on my template if i do that, but when i go to the PK without "accessconfirmed"
i get this error

KeyError

Exception Type: KeyError

Exception Value:    'data'

line 62 -  ...'gimmeprice':api_price['data'][api_coin_number_variable]['quote']['USD']['price'],....

**please advise what I am doing wrong**

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT.

i realized that the if statement was just checking if access was confirmed instead of checking if access was confirmed for every individual object so i switched it from

```
if accessconfirmed:
```

to

```
if coin.is_api_access:
```

and everything is good now, leaving this up incase someone runs in to similar issues